# osclass jquery doesnt work correct

Tags: jquery, osclass

I use jQuery price selector . the code in another pages work but in osclass not . the input tag in osclass will texbox in another page is normal . CSS and js files in both were declare.

```
<div class="layout-slider" style="width: 100%">
  Slider <span style="display: inline-block; width: 400px; padding: 0 5px;"><input id="Slider1" type="slider" name="price" value="30000.5;60000" /></span>  in string
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  jQuery("#Slider1").slider({ from: 1000, to: 100000, step: 500, smooth: true, round: 0, dimension: "&nbsp;$", skin: "plastic" });
</script>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any error in web browser console?

Comment: The network tab is also without errors?

Comment: this error //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null // but this is for another jquery

Comment: But sometimes when one error occurs the rest of the code in javascript is not processed.

Comment: what do you think about input tag?

Comment: That CSS did not load correctly. Can you share link to your page?

Comment: the error in console is : {
 return Spry.is.safari && (event.target == event.relatedTarget.parentNode || (event.eventPhase == 3 && event.target.parentNode == event.relatedTarget));
}; and the link of anoraml jquery is here www.loso.ch the normal is that www.seta.rotsab.com

Answer (score 0):

You don't include `jquery.slider.js` in your page and/or jqueryUI libraries.

Comment: Thank you , But this file is for Price selector

Answer (score 0):

If you run code in Osclass, always use

`$(document)ready(function(){ ... Your code ... });`

Just to make sure that jQuery is loaded before your code.